# Downloading list of files in parallel in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a simple text file which contains list of folders on some FTP servers. Each line is a separate folder. Each folder contains couple of thousand images. I want to connect to each folder, store all files inside that foder in a `SequenceFile` and then remove that folder from FTP server. I have written a simple pig UDF for this. Here it is:

```
dirs = LOAD '/var/location.txt' USING PigStorage();
results = FOREACH dirs GENERATE download_whole_folder_into_single_sequence_file($0);
/* I don't need results bag. It is just a dummy bag */
```

The problem is I'm not sure if each line of input is processed in separate mapper. The input file is not a huge file just couple of hundred lines. If it were pure `Map/Reduce` then I would use `NLineInputFormat` and process each line in a separate `Mapper`. How can I achieve the same thing in pig?

Comment: Just curious why you are using `Pig` to accomplish this task?

Comment: @GoBrewers14 Nothing. Just trying to learn...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pig lets you write your own [load functions](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/udf.html#load-store-functions), which let you specify which InputFormat you'll be using. So you could write your own.

That said, the job you described sounds like it would only involve a single map-reduce step. Since using Pig wouldn't reduce complexity in this case, and you'd have to write custom code just to use Pig, I'd suggest just doing it in vanilla map-reduce. If the total file size is Gigabytes or less, I'd just do it all directly on a single host. It's simpler not to use map reduce if you don't have to.

I typically use map-reduce to first load data into HDFS, and then Pig for all data processing. Pig doesn't really add any benefits over vanilla hadoop for loading data IMO, it's just a wrapper around InputFormat/RecordReader with additional methods you need to implement. Plus it's technically possible with Pig that your loader will be called multiple times. That's a gotcha you don't need to worry about using Hadoop map-reduce directly.